# Different Top Answerers lists for same tag in different places

Tags: discussion, bug, top-users

In the top answerers section for `All time` in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pentaho/topusers) shows my name in 6th place. But in `info` section of the tag [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pentaho/info) shows my name in 5th place. Why there are two different calculation logic for the same top answerers list in two different places?

[image: All time top answerers]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are correct.

The two of you have 52 votes so it is undeterministic which of you will be fifth and which sixth when ordered by that value.

Perhaps it should be ordered by `upvotes DESC, number_of_answers ASC` so the person with the highest average is ordered first in that case (though there will still also be a possibility of ties in that case too and something unique such as userid could be used as a final tiebreaker to ensure stable results).

**Edit**

And now there's a three way tie for 4th/5th/6th place. The person featured 4th on the all time list...

[image]

...  doesn't even make the top 5 in the other list.

[image]

Comment: @pnuts Apparently so. Or the two would be the same. It might calculate the `TOP 20` then have the cut down list do a `TOP 5` from that `TOP 20`.

Comment: @pnuts I agree with you. `better to recalc 5 from 20 than 20 from 5`. Still we can say its a bug since it effects efficiency.

Comment: oh haha.. just noticed